# Catching Missing Semicolons in C header file prototypes

Tags: c, gcc, header, warnings

This topic ought to have been flogged to death. I just spent 30 minutes locating what ended up being a missing semicolon at the end of a function prototype in a header file:

```
void foo(void);
void bar(void)  // <<< Error on this line
void squee(void);
```

This is a common typo caused by copy-pasting the prototype from the C file.  Of course according to the compiler the universe just fell apart, with an endless stream of absolutely nonsensical errors, none of them helpful.

This could be avoided by having an optional parsing phase to check for this condition in .h files then report a warning (promoted to error if settings mandate). This would require some restrictions on what you put in header files (no code, consistent format for prototypes, etc).  But that's an easy compromise.

I can write my own SW tool to do this, but it would be more helpful to run it as a part of the build process. I use GCC in Eclipse. Any advice on where you'd start with this? Or anything pre-existing / off the shelf? Or perhaps just a better way to approach it?

Thank you.

Comment: The problem is that when the compiler sees the code for syntax checking, there's no such things as "header files". All the compiler knows after pre-processing is the current [*translation unit*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)).

Comment: And not to mention that the "restrictions" imposed would make it a new "similar to, but not quite C" language.

Comment: Yip, it would have to a a pre-processing step, like static analysis. Heck it could even be a part of CODAN (Eclipse).

Comment: Restrictions: It's still C, but you just set intentional rules, such as Don't end a prototype with a bracket on line N, and the semicolon on line N+1. Then it's trivial to parse, regexp for instance.

Comment: @radsdau "*endless stream of absolutely nonsensical errors*" Always focus on the *first* error. In this case it's `expected initializer before 'void'`, and it points to the line *next* to the one you indicate. If you look at what's `before 'void'` it shouldn't take long to realize that there is a missing semicolon on the line above it.

Comment: Sadly that's not what I got. In an apparently unrelated .h file, I get "error: storage class specified for parameter 'foux' then about 50 the same. In hindsight I can infer enough, but it's no fun to spend so much time on such a trivial typo.
In general though, good tip- thanks.

Comment: `gcc` is pretty good [it has gotten better]. But, `clang` sometimes has better diagnostic messages. A number of years ago, I had a file that compiled _fine_ with `gcc -Wall -O2`. But, runtime results were incorrect. `gdb` showed nothing [that I could see]. Spent [at least] a week desk checking. In desperation [thinking it was a `gcc` code gen bug], I tried `clang`. It _flagged_ the issue immediately as it had more warnings enabled by default. Turned out I had (e.g.): `if (x); y = 5;` instead of `if (x) y = 5;` I had to add `-Wextra` to `gcc` to get the warning.

Comment: @radsdau The error in my previous comment is what [gcc issues](https://godbolt.org/z/9oKr7s) for the code you posted. If your real code is vastly different from that, you'll get different errors, of course.

Comment: It's always a good idea to raise the warning level to the maximum, on GCC at least `-Wall -Wextra`. -- @radsdau Would you mind to show us a [example] of the situation with the error you got (_"storage class specified for parameter 'foux'"_)? -- You could try to write a source file that includes all headers but has to other code. Then check this with any capable static code checker, including Clang.

Answer (score 1):

it's far more common and more difficult to guess the following problem (in a header file):

```
struct something {
   type1 var1;
   type2 var2;
}
/* EOF */
```

and when you `#include "header.h"` into `hello.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "header.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        printf("Hello, world\n");
}
```

you get an error e.g.

```
lcu@europa:~$ gcc main.c
main.c:4:1: error: expected ';', identifier or '(' before 'int'
    4 | int main(int argc, char **argv)
      | ^~~
```

and the compiler has got out of `header.h` to signal the error in the line of `main` function.  The thing can be worse if you happen to use legacy code and declare `main()` the old way:

```
main(argc, argv)
char **argv;
{
...
```

because then, the `struct` is a valid type and it is taken as the type returned by `main()`  and you get (if you get it) the error far below (or no error at all, just a warning):

```
lcu@europa:~$ gcc main.c
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:4:1: warning: type of 'argc' defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
    4 | main(argc, argv)
      | ^~~~
```

In this case, the contents of main.c were:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "header.h"

main(argc, argv)
char **argv;
{
        printf("Hello, world\n");
}
```

which is still valid c code.

(these examples were made by gcc, because clang ---the native compiler of freebsd--- detects the EOF in the header file and shows a warning stating that the type was not ended before the end of the include file.  But this only happens if the type definition is the last of the file.

#### Note:

if you declare main as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "header.h"

main(argc, argv)
int argc;
char **argv;
{
        printf("Hello, world\n");
}
```

you get a complete compilation, without even a warning.